# expected ')' error in Xcode when giving an address to function

Tags: c

There is a little arrow under the "&" and if I remove it, it works.
Im new to Xcode and i'm pretty sure this would compile on my old PC. I had previous declared in the code booth the struct and the variable barra.

```
void InitBarra(struct Barra &barra)
{
    barra.x = WIDTH/2;
    barra.y = HEIGHT;
    barra.vidas = 3;
    barra.velocidade = 7;
    barra.placar = 0;
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Xcode.  You appear to be trying to compile C++ code with a C (or Objective-C, maybe) compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really should be a pointer:

```
void InitBarra(Barra *barra)
{
    barra->x = WIDTH/2;
    barra->y = HEIGHT;
    barra->vidas = 3;
    barra->velocidade = 7;
    barra->placar = 0;
}
```

Where the Barra struct is declared and/or malloc'd from the calling function.